# How to identify window under mouse with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
id eventHandler = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent * event) {
    CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[event windowNumber];
    CFArrayRef a = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&windowID, 1, NULL);
    NSArray *windowInfos = (__bridge NSArray *)CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(a);
    CFRelease(a);
    if ([windowInfos count] > 0) {
        NSDictionary *windowInfo = [windowInfos objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Name:  %@", [windowInfo objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowName]);
        NSLog(@"Owner: %@", [windowInfo objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerName]);
        //etc.
    }
}];
```

Which does a pretty good job at identifying windows under the cursor.  However, in order to identify them reliably you must click on the window.  Some windows will trigger a change such as terminal and xcode, but hovering over say the desktop does not trigger that Finder is under the cursor.  However if you click on the desktop then it is correctly identified.  Any ideas what I might be missing?